# Get values from an array using array of indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I need key/values from, and an array of indexes:

```
$reference = [
    'a' => 'this is A',
    'b' => 'here is B',
    'c' => 'C here',
    'd' => 'finally, d',
];

$indexArray = [1, 3];
```

I want my result to be:

```
$result = [
    'b' => 'here is B',
    'd' => 'finally, d',
];
```

Currently what I have is:

```
$result = array_intersect(
    $reference,
    array_map(
        function ($index) { return array_values($reference)[$index]; },
        $indexArray
    )
);
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is a built-in function that can already do this.
I know `array_slice` can do something like this if the values are next to each other, but is there another function that can slice based on an array of indexes?

**Edited**

This actually doesn't work unless my `$reference` array in constant. So, again, good solution if `$reference` isn't constant?

Comment: Why are you using numeric indexes for an associative array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_intersect_key()` after using `array_flip()` to convert `$indexArray` to an array whose keys are the values.

```
$result = array_intersect_key(array_values($reference), array_flip($indexArray));
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the keys though, unless I intersect again with $reference

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you were trying to do that.

Comment: As I said earlier, it's very strange to be using numeric indexes for an associative array.

Comment: Are the values guaranteed to be unique? Your `array_intersect()` won't work if there are duplicate values.

Comment: In this case values are unique. Kinda hard to explain quickly why I'm using numeric indexes, but it doesn't seem that strange to me considering you can get these indexes using `array_keys` and `array_values`.

Answer (score 0):

My approach can be written as a one-liner by nesting the functions inside of each other, but I will employ single-use variables to better express the functionality with intuitive variable names.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/a4q1R))

```
$reference = [
    'a' => 'this is A',
    'b' => 'here is B',
    'c' => 'C here',
    'd' => 'finally, d',
];

$indexesToKeep = [1, 3];
$mapKeysToIndexes = array_flip(array_keys($reference));
$keysToKeep = array_intersect($mapKeysToIndexes, $indexesToKeep);
var_export(array_intersect_key($reference, $keysToKeep));

/* var_export(
       array_intersect_key(
           $reference,
           array_intersect(
               array_flip(
                   array_keys($reference)
               ),
               $indexesToKeep
           )
       )
   ); */
```

Output:

```
array (
  'b' => 'here is B',
  'd' => 'finally, d',
)
```

---

Or you can achieve the same result with more efficient time complexity by incrementing a index/counter variable as you iterate.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Tvl0l))

```
$lookup = array_flip($indexesToKeep);
$index = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($reference as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($lookup[$index])) {
        $result[$key] = $value;
    }
    ++$index;
}
var_export($result);
```